# Authorization Issue with Specific MarketSharp API Endpoint

Tags: authentication, github-third-party-apps

I'm working with the MarketSharp API and encountered an authorization issue with a specific endpoint, even though other endpoints are functioning correctly with the same token.

Endpoint:
`https://restapi.marketsharpm.com/companies/2453/activities/types?includeInactive=false&api-version=1.0`

Error:

> "Authorization has been denied for this request."

Steps tried:

1. Verified the API token and ensured it's correctly passed in the headers.
2. Checked the endpoint URL for typos or discrepancies.
3. Reviewed MarketSharp's official API documentation for any endpoint-specific requirements.

Other MarketSharp API endpoints are working correctly with this token. I'm unsure why only this specific endpoint is causing an issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on potential solutions or things I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Some MarketSharp API endpoints require additional permissions for access. In our situation, our application ID lacked the necessary permissions for the desired endpoint. However, after granting those permissions, the endpoint now appears to be functioning correctly. I hope it may help someone.